# How to identify the youtube channel of a deleted video?

Tags: youtube, archiving

Every now and then, video URL I noted down (instead of bookmarking) turn out to have been deleted/removed or not be viewable in a way or another, and youtube doesn't redirect me to the channel's page nor give me any hint as to what the video or the channel was.

I tried checking on the archives.org but those channels are too small to be saved.

How can I identify the youtube channel from one of its video URL ?